# setting the document root in the apache

Tags: php, apache

I have php(wamp) installed in 'E' drive. Actually, my project in the 'F:' drive.

How do i set the document root in apache httpd.conf file to access the project in F: drive.

For example, if i enter "http://127.0.0.1/projectname", it should point to the 'F' drive project.

Comment: Even though the third bullet of the [faq] says 'software tools commonly used by programmers' and wamp is clearly one of these tools this was migrated to SF where developer tools like WAMP are considered off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change document root then find **<Directory** in *httpd.conf* and change it there. It most likely reads **<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">** now or similar. Once you've changed it and saved it you can restart WAMP.

On the other hand if you just want to have that one project "http://localhost/thisproject" to point somewhere else you can just use an alias.

1. Click the WAMP icon by the clock.
2. go to *Apache* > *Alias Directories* and click **Add an Alias**
3. Follow the prompts.
4. Restart WAMP